# Object Management in String Pool ofJava

Tags: java, string, garbage-collection

Hi i am working in java and want to know how String objects are created in the String pool
 and how they are managed.

So in the following example i am creating two Strings s and s1,so can anyone explain me how many Objects are created in LIne1?Also how many Objects are eligible for garbage collection in Line3?

```
  String s = "x" + "y";//Line 1
  String s1 = s;//Line 2
  s = null;//Line 3
```

Answer (score 3):

Only one object is created `"xy"` . compiler does it for optimization.

No object is eligible for garbage collection.

Comment: So Objects "x" and "y" will not get created in the pool?My understanding is(which might be wrong) three object will be created.

Comment: @JavaGeek That will only happen if you force it to create a new object, with `new String(string)`

Comment: No. Concatenation of many literals in single line will create single object. Compiler generates such optimized code which will end up with single object.

Answer (score 0):

It would create one object `xy` in the String constant pool area. As `"x"+"y"` would be evaluated during compilation. Additionally, garbage collector cannot access String constant pool area.

Reference: https://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se7/html/jls-3.html#jls-3.10.5